# I Don't want to overwrite or save same file name

Tags: c#, .net

I have Made a register system. But the problem is that the file of same name has been overwriten or renamed . for an example
if my file name is

Fasih.txt

now I want to do if another user use same name Fasih then Message box show error and doesn't overwrite Or renamed that file .

```
  private void btnCreate_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        System.IO.TextWriter tw = new System.IO.StreamWriter(txtUsername.Text + ".txt");
        tw.WriteLine(txtPassword.Text);
        tw.Close();
        tw.Dispose();
        this.Close();
        if (File.Exists(txtUsername.Text + ".txt"))
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Already used ", "Use diferent name");
```

Comment: Show us what you've tried and what exactly isn't working.  Add some code.

Comment: I've added the code from your comment to your question, which you should do next time.  Click the Edit link below the question body, or better yet, add it as you are asking the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something like that:

```
private void btnCreate_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) {
  String fileName = Path.Combine(txtUsername.Text, ".txt");

  if (File.Exists(fileName)) 
    MessageBox.Show("Already used ", "Use diferent name");
  else { 
    // OK
    File.WriteAllText(fileName, txtPassword.Text); 

    Close(); // if you want to close form here
  }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

In your code example, you already write to the file before checking to see if it exists, so the file will always exist.  You need to check *before* you write to the file.

Something like:

```
private void btnCreate_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) {
    var filename = txtUsername.Text + ".txt";

    if (File.Exists(filename))
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Already used ", "Use different name");
    }
    else
    {
        System.IO.TextWriter tw = new System.IO.StreamWriter(filename);
        tw.WriteLine(txtPassword.Text);
        tw.Close();
        tw.Dispose();
        this.Close();
    }
```